# Help for an integral: $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^k(1+x)^{n-k}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm working in a problem and I want to compute the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^k(1+x)^{n-k}dx$$

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try using binomial theorem,then multiply out,then find antiderivative of whole expression since it will basically be a polynomial of degree n,and then use second fundamental theorem to give general formula .I am just guessing without pen and paper,since it is very late

Comment: Ok, thanks I will continue working in it

Comment: Integration by parts seems like it would work if you take $1-x$ to zero. You'll end up with some type of series of factorial terms. The $uv$ term which can be a pain in this case will be easy since your two terms are trivial to evaluate when $x=1,0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^j(1-x)^k\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(j+k+2)}$$
it follows that:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^k(1+x)^{n-k}\,dx = \sum_{h=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-h}{k}\frac{\Gamma(h+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(h+k+2)}\\=\sum_{h=0}^{n-k}\frac{(n-k)!h!}{(n-h-k)!(h+k+1)!}$$
or, in terms of the [incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html):
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}x^k (2-x)^{n-k}\,dx = 2^{n+1}\cdot B\left(\frac{1}{2};k+1,n-k+1\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n$, and let $I_k=\int_0^1(1-x)^k(1+x)^{n-k}\,dx$. Using integration by parts, we have

\begin{align}
I_k &= \frac{1}{n-(k-1)}\left(1+kI_{k-1}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n-(k-1)}\left(1+\frac{k}{n-(k-2)}\left(1+(k-1)I_{k-2}\right)\right) \\
&\vdots \\
&= \sum_{\nu=0}^k\frac{(k!)/(k-\nu)!}{\prod_{\mu=1}^{\nu+1}(n-(k-\mu))}.
\end{align}

For a technical proof, it might be better to induct on $k$. This is how I thought about it, though.